# Can the following be achieved using MYSQL union?

Tags: mysql

We have a Web Analytics database with 2 tables Table 1 and Table 2 as seen below.
[image]

We really could do with some inputs here to display the desired result as a single row.

Many Thanks

X

Comment: There is no common data item that would link Purchase A2 to Quote_received_1.  How do you know they go together?

Comment: Jim, the Reference data and cookieid is common between the 2 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    A.Name,
    A.ref_num Policy_number,
    B.QNum Quote_number
FROM
    (
        SELECT AA.Name,BB.ref_num FROM
        (SELECT Name,ref_num FROM Table1 WHERE Name='Purchase' AND Cookieid=123456) AA
        INNER JOIN Table2 BB USING (Reference)
    ) A,
    (
        SELECT BB.ref_num QNum FROM
        (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Name='Quote' AND Cookieid=123456) AA
        INNER JOIN Table2 BB USING (Reference)
    ) B
;
```

All you have to do is set the Cookieid in both subqueries.

Make sure you have this index:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD INDEX Cookieid_Name_ndx (Cookieid,Name);
```

Comment: Thanks Rolando. The sub queries when executed on their own works fine, but if I run the entire query it throws a syntax error "1064 syntax error near ( SELECT BB.ref_num QNum.....)